# Smooth dented circle with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to create a circle with a notch in it.

My code does not produce the desired result, as there are some areas which do not appear smooth and at position (3,0) there is a break in the line.
The control points I set are guesswork.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1)   and (2,1)    .. (3,0);
    \draw (0,0) .. controls (-1,0)  and (-3,3)   .. (0,5);
    \draw (0,5) .. controls (1,5.5) and (2,5.5)  .. (3,5);
    \draw (3,5) .. controls (5.5,4) and (4.5,0)  .. (3,0);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there any (automatic) function in TikZ which can create a smooth dented circle?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sketch of what you're aiming for?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thank you. I added a low quality image of the desired shape above. The color is secondary. It is just a quick sketch.

Comment: Hi isn't it cardioid?

Comment: Do a search with `hobby` keyword. You'll find what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using Bézier curves without any issue, but better done in one curve, and with fine control of the control points:

[image: Bezier curve]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt,cyan] 
        \draw   (0,0)   .. controls ++(.75,0)   and ++ (-.75,0) ..
                (2,.5)  .. controls ++(.75,0)   and ++ (-.75,0) ..
                (4,0)   .. controls ++(3,0)     and ++ (4,0) ..
                (2,6)   .. controls ++(-4,0)    and ++ (-3,0) ..
                (0,0) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here I used relative positions for the control points (hence the `++` with the `controls`) to allow moving the drawing points without having to change everything. Just play with it.

Comment: I choose this post, however your comment about the hobby-package above was even more helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I had a second version using Hobby but you can't control a hobby curve as much as you can a Bézier curve, so as it was a less accurate design, I didn't add it to my answer. But however, the Hobby package is a wonder for many reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Overlay a grid (tracing paper?) on the shape, add as many points as you can, then generate a smooth plot joining them.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[smooth cycle] plot[tension=0.9] coordinates{(-0.5,0) (1.5,0.5) (3.5,0) (4.5,2.5) (3,5) (0,5) (-1.5,2.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```